# Dreamweaver regular expression substitution followed by number

Tags: regex, dreamweaver

I'm using Dreamweaver to update copyright dates across my site.  I want to preserve the existing spacing (or lack thereof) between years.  Examples:
© 2002-2008 should update to © 2002-2009
© 2003 - 2008 should update to © 2003 - 2009
This is the regular expression I'm using to accomplish this in Dreamweaver's find & replace function
Find:
©\s*(\d{4}\s*-\s*)\d{3}[^9]

Replace:
© $1 2009

Here's the PROBLEM:
This expression works, but has that that extra space between the hyphen and 2009.  If I write the replace expression without the space, as © $12009 then dreamweaver looks for the 12,009th substitution in the find expression, and, not finding one, prints $12009.

Comment: Same problem. In PCRE you can write \{1} to "protect" the reference number, but not finding the info for Dreamweaver. Certainly ${1} does not work.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not capture the - as well as the whitespace before or after it and only capture the leading year, then it'll make life a bit easier:
©\s*(\d{4})\s*-\s*\d{3}[^9]
then replace with:
@ $1 - 2009

Just tried locally and it worked in the following test cases:

```
© 2002- 2008
© 2002-2005
© 2002- 2006
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not have Dreamweaver, but I suppose that its regex engine doesn't support lookaround - at least [this introduction from Adobe](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/regular_expressions_print.html) doesn't mention it. So you'll need a workaround. One thing you could do (not pretty, but it works):

Use `© $1QQQQ2009` as your replacement string, and then do a second pass, searching for `QQQQ` and replacing that with nothing. As long as you're sure that you don't have any real occurences of `QQQQ` in your text somewhere :)